# How to align Bootstrap 4 button that is using the file selector?

Tags: html, file-upload, bootstrap-4, file-io

I have 3 buttons that are using Bootstrap. I can't seem to get the 3 buttons to align horizontally on the same line. The first button, which is the file selector seems to be doing a line break. How do I stop it from breaking to the next line?

Here is my HTML. As well as a link to a w3schools test sample.

```
<div style="background-color:rgb(214, 153, 226)">
    <!-- Image File Selector Button -->
    <div>
        <label for="fileSelectImages" class="btn btn-primary">Select Photos</label>
        <input id="fileSelectImages" type='file' style="visibility: hidden;" accept="image/*" multiple>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Clear Photos</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload Photos</button>  
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJG3DPURXIXB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of the file input, it took the spaces and made the other buttons go down. Putting `position:absolute;` on the input will do the trick.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background-color:rgb(214, 153, 226)">
    <!-- Image File Selector Button -->
    
        <label for="fileSelectImages" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ml-2">Select Photos</label>
        <input id="fileSelectImages" type='file' style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute;" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Clear Photos</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload Photos</button>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. Works perfectly.

Comment: One strange thing was w3schools vertical alignment was off just a tad when I left out the {mt-2 ml-2} on the label but my Angular html didn't need it. Still left it on like your example had though. Thanks for you reply :)